# How to rename an Android app programmatically?

Tags: android, rename

Some users want to rename my Android app to something else.

So I'd like to provide a text field for them to put in a new name inside my app.
Then how can I programmatically rename my app name to the new name?

Comment: I guess your users are looking for this? [https://www.technologyhint.com/change-android-icons-names/](https://www.technologyhint.com/change-android-icons-names/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to rename your app or change the title when application is running?

To change the title you have setTtle() funcion from activity.

If you want to change application name in string.xml you should have a value called app_name.

You have to rename it to the new value.

To do so you have to unzip the apk and modify the xml file and then repack it.

But making this way I think application have to be reinstalled.